# What value is in EAX after execution of each instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers, masm32

I am trying to track the EAX register through each snippet of the code in a MASM32 program. I need help with explaining why it is the value it is. This is what I have:

```
.DATA
 alfa BYTE 96h

.CODE
 start:

 MOV EAX,0  ; move 0 to eax 
 MOV AL,alfa ; move 96h to AL, this says the value of eax is now positive 150
 MOVZX EAX,alfa ; still says EAX is 96h and value is  positive 150
 MOVSX EAX,alfa  ; says value is negative 106 and eax register is FFFFFF96

 call DumpRegs
 call WriteInt
exit
END start
```

I am using `DumpRegs` to display the registers and `WriteInt` to print the value of EAX. I have some questions:

1. When `MOV AL, alfa`, it moves `alfa` into the EAX register, isn't AL an 8-bit register? why does it do this? Why does `WriteInt` say that the value is +150?
2. What do `MOVZX` and `MOVSX` do?
3. What does `MOVZX EAX, alfa` do? None of the values had changed?
4. `MOVSX EAX, alfa`, why is it -106 and the EAX register FFFFFF96? Is it because it is negative?

Comment: What each instruction does should be explained in the processor manual. If there is something in the processor manual you don't understand, please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You initialze `eax` to 0 so the value is 0

```
mov eax, 0
EAX-----
    AX--
    AHAL
00000000

mov al, 96h

EAX-----
    AX--
    AHAL
00000096
```

The remainder of the register doesn't change when AL is adressed, so it stays the same.

To illustrate this:

```
mov eax, -1
EAX-----
    AX--
    AHAL
ffffffff

mov al, 96h

EAX-----
    AX--
    AHAL
ffffff96
```

`movesx`  loads the value with sign extension. Since 096h is a negative (highest bit is set) it will extend the sign to the whole 32 bit register.

`movzx` doe not sign extend and clears the bits.

Comment: Thank you for your help again! Is there any reason though why the call WriteInt is printing +150?